# how to get request Ajax get acess wp function

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a class, and an interface in a plugin that I’m building, this interface needs access to functions to list the worpress categories. How to include the files needed to use native wordpress functions. Since the request is made to this interface by ajax. Any Ideas?

```
    this.RequestVideos = function(){
       var dados        = {};
    dados.KeywordUrl = escape($('#termo_pesquisa').val());
    dados.categoria  = $('#categorias').val();
    dados.ordenacao  = 'sponsor';
    dados.host       = Importer.GetSponsors();
    dados.duracao    = $('#duracao').val();
    $.get('/wp-content/plugins/mega-importer/class/Importer.interface.php',dados,function(resposta, status){
      Importer.EsconderPainelImportacao();
      $('#videos_search').html(resposta);
      $('.duracao').mask('00:00:00');
    });
  }
```

I need to have access within my Importer.interface.php the native functions of wordpress to be able to retrieve from the database a list of available categories

Thank you any advanced!

Update, Plano B (get all categories e ids the option select existent in my page e send to importer.interface.php)

Wordpress causes me an absurd frustration. Why not to any separation between html, javascript, php, and database. Everything is totally mixed up like a big trash. I spent 20 years of my time as a programmer and a lot of them getting away from writing wordpress plugins. At the end if you still want a documentation with examples of functioning, you will encounter text all in English where the language barrier will disrupt the total understanding and the worst without any functional example that clarifies your doubt. Thank you for your work but I'm going to Plan B creative.

```
this.GetAllCategorias    = function(){
    var obj                = [];
    var ids                = new Array();
    var labels             = new Array();
    $("#categorias option").each(function(){
        ids.push($(this).val());
        labels.push($(this).text());
    });
    obj.push(ids.join());
    obj.push(labels.join());
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
  }
```

Comment: You should not be making a request to the specific URL path of your plugin in the first place here, that is not how this is supposed to work. Your plugin should register the appropriate actions instead. Suggest you start with https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins, that explains how to do this properly.

Comment: Plan B sorry, I wrote you a message above. Thank you very much